# Why doesn't table resize work here? jsfiddle url inserted

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, jquery-ui-resizable

How can I make my `table` resizable like a textarea element and
not individual rows/columns? I seem to be fundamentally missing something simple.

https://jsfiddle.net/o0Ldf0us/

```
<table id="example">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Heading1</th>
        <th>Heading2</th>
        <th>Heading3</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Data1.1</td>
        <td>Data1.2</td>
        <td>Data1.3</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Data2.1</td>
        <td>Data2.2</td>
        <td>Data2.3</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Data3.1</td>
        <td>Data3.2</td>
        <td>Data3.3</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

```css
#example, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```js
$("#example").resizable();
```

Comment: Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/euka4rm3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `resizable` method is not part of the standard jQuery library - it's part of [jQueryUI](http://api.jqueryui.com/), so you need to include that too. Once you've done that your code will work:

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/o0Ldf0us/1/)

Comment: Thanks! So I included <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script> But it doesn't work, why?

Comment: That should be fine. Just ensure you're including `jquery.js` *before* `jquery.ui.js` and also that there are no errors in the console